# Discord.py Edit Channel when the Bot goes offline

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Here my Code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_disconnect():
    channel = bot.get_channel(1064939978569822309)
    await channel.edit(name="Bot status: ")
```

I dont have any errors but nothing happends if the bot disconnect.
Can anyone help me?

I reinstall the library.

Answer (score 1):

According to [discord.py's documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_disconnect). `on_disconnect()` is used for when the bot cannot connect to the discord server.

If the bot cannot connect to the server, it would not be able to get the discord channel (think about it, if you can't connect to discord you would not be able to send any message at all, much less editing the channel).

`on_disconnect()` is probably more for the usage on the local side of things (e.g. printing out logs to check why the bot cannot connect to the discord server) rather than to update the bot's status.

It is not possible to do this automatically, unless you have another bot monitoring this bot (which is not really viable as both bots could be down at the same time).

If you want to handle cases where you have to shutdown the bot (for maintenance purposes, as an example), you can instead have a function (an idea is you can have it as a discord command that can only be run by the bot's owner) to edit the channel before going offline.